# Is it possible to load formula from excel file into grid view using c#?

Tags: excel-2007, c#-2.0

**Consider this example:**
I have an excel file in which I have data in two columns like below-

```
Salary  Commission  Net Payable
1000        5             1050
2000       10             2200
3000       15             3450
4000       20             4800
```

The formula used to calculate the Net Payable is : `A2+((A2*B2)/100)`
Where **A2 = Salary (here 1000)**, and **B2 = Commission (here 5)**
When I load these data from excel file into grid view, it only loads the values like above. 
**My question is: Is there any way so that I can load the internal formula also in grid view?** Something like **A2+((A2*B2)/100) in a grid view column**?   Its not any development project. I just wonder if this could be done? Thanks.

**Edit: The code I am using to load data**

```
try
        {
            rst = CMDExcel.ExecuteReader();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox("Error in reading Operation data from excel file");
            return;
        }

        while (rst.Read())
        {
            sSalary = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                sSalary = rst("Salary").ToString().Trim();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            if (sSalary.Length > 0)
            {
                DGMAIN.Rows.Add();

                try
                {
                    DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_SALARY").Value = rst("Salary").ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
                try
                {
                    DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_COMMISSION").Value = rst("Commission").ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
                try
                {
                    DGMAIN.Rows(i).Cells("DGMAIN_NET_PAYABLE").Value = rst("Net Payable").ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }

                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        rst.Close();
```

There is no problem with the code as it loads data correctly into grid view.

Comment: yes it can definitely be done.

Comment: Any suggestion about where/how to start will be great :)

Comment: how are you loading the data? show your code